# Semaphore CI using environment conditions in "when" clauses

Tags: continuous-integration, semaphore, semaphore-ci

I'm trying to only run a Semaphore CI job when it's being ran by the automated scheduler.

To do this, the docs has the environment variable `SEMAPHORE_WORKFLOW_TRIGGERED_BY_SCHEDULE`.

I'm trying to use this in the `when` clause.  e.g.

```
  dependencies: [System Tests]
  run:
    when: "SEMAPHORE_WORKFLOW_TRIGGERED_BY_SCHEDULE = true"
```

This does not work, I get the error

```
Unprocessable YAML file.
Error: "Invalid 'when' condition on path '#/blocks/5/run/when': 
Syntax error on line 1. - Invalid expression on the left of '=' operator."
```

Referring to the env variable with a `$` doesn't work either, as apparently in the when clause it's an invalid character.

How can I only run the CI job when it's scheduled?

Answer (score 1):

`when` doesn't support environment variables. It only supports the notation specified here: https://docs.semaphoreci.com/reference/conditions-reference/.

Let me get your use case straight. Do you want to run specific blocks based on whether the pipeline is executed from the scheduler or not? If that's the case, `when` will not help you, unfortunately.

However, I think I can provide a workaround by using an IF statement. You could add all the commands from the job inside an IF statement that checks `SEMAPHORE_WORKFLOW_TRIGGERED_BY_SCHEDULE`. This way, if the variable matches you run the commands, if not you skip all the commands and the job ends successfully there. Effectively "skipping" the job with almost no execution time. Something like, please check if the syntax is correct:

```
if [ SEMAPHORE_WORKFLOW_TRIGGERED_BY_SCHEDULE = true ]; then run commands; else echo "skip commands"; fi
```